# Getting started with CAN bus

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, can-bus

I have configured the device as said in these links 
1. http://www.cowfishstudios.com/blog/canned-pi-part1
2. http://lnxpps.de/rpie/

But the problem is the terminal hangs/ seems busy after i enter this command

candump -cae can0,0:0,#FFFFFFFF

What are the configurations i need to check again?..i guess the SPI works fine (as the red LED glows).

Comment: Are you able to execute any other socketCAN utilities?

Comment: Write an answer to your own question then and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem ,i tried to install cross compiler modules for the older version 3.10.24+ but those configurations were already installed .so i just upgraded the version and it works fine now.